Undefined reference to function (Prob makefile error)
I have a code that is not running probably because a error in my makefile file. I have to run 3 functions from a external library but i cant use them because of thet undefined error
My implementation of the makefile archive
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -c -O2 -Wall
LDFLAGS =

all: zoom

zoom: lib_ppm.o zoom.o
  $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) lib_ppm.o zoom.o -o zoom

lib_ppm.o: lib_ppm.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c lib_ppm.c

zoom.o: zoom.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c zoom.c


clean:
  -rm -f *.o *~ zoom lena_copy.ppm test.ppm

lib_ppm.o: lib_ppm.h


The call of the functions on the main:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lib_ppm.h"

int main() {
/... logic .../
entry = read_ppm("lena.ppm", image_in);
if(entry < 0)
{
    printf("read_ppm error");
    return 0;
}  
/... logic .../
entry = new_ppm(image_out, data.width*3, data.height*3);
if( entry < 0)
{
    printf("new_ppm error");
    return 0;
}  
/... logic .../

entry = write_ppm("copy.ppm", image_out);
if( entry < 0)
{
    printf("read_ppm error");
    return 0;
}
}

the .h file
struct pixel_s {
    unsigned char r, g, b;
};

struct image_s {
    int width;
    int height;
    struct pixel_s *pix;
};

int read_ppm(char *file, struct image_s *image);
int write_ppm(char *file, struct image_s *image);
int new_ppm(struct image_s *image, int width, int height);
int free_ppm(struct image_s *image);

output:
make
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -c zoom.c
gcc  lib_ppm.o zoom.o -o zoom

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoHFVnw.o: in function `main':
/workspaces/softwarebasico/zoom.c:13: undefined reference to `read_ppm'
/usr/bin/ld: /workspaces/softwarebasico/zoom.c:20: undefined reference to `new_ppm'
/usr/bin/ld: /workspaces/softwarebasico/zoom.c:48: undefined reference to `write_ppm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

That was the instruction i was expecting from the makefile, but im unsure about the .h parameter on "lib_ppm.o: lib_ppm.h"

Your content after "output" is not complete.  You didn't include the commands that make invoked.  Also it's not correctly formatted as a code block and so is not very readable.  Assuming that the functions are actually defined properly in the lib_ppm.c file then I don't see why you should get this error based on that makefile.  So we'll need to see exactly what commands make is running to be sure it's actually using that makefile correctly.  Also you should look at the implementation of lib_ppm.c and make sure the functions are defined there, and aren't static or something.

sorry for that, its my first stack overflow question and im still learning haha. Here is the make output!
gcc -c -O2 -Wall -c zoom.c
gcc  lib_ppm.o zoom.o -o zoom
All the fucntions are defined as int in lib_ppm.c. I can edit the main question to put the lib_ppm.c there if u need!

Why are there weird backslashes in the Makefile and zoom.c?

Please edit the question and add the commands make printed to your question, and fix the formatting of the output to use a code block so that newlines are handled correctly.  I can't interpret the text as shown in the comment.

Think it was because i misscliked "inline code" before. Think i fixed it now, thx for telling

MadScientist, i eddited there. Think it is formated now

Try removing lib_ppm.o and running make again. We haven't seen it get compiled, so we don't know how it got compiled.

which instances of lib_ppm.o? all of it?

@IanAbbott: Backslashes are caused by a Stack Overflow UI problem. I do not know the details, but I suspect pasting text into some aspect of the UI automatically quotes various characters by inserting backslashes. At this point, that markup displays correctly as ordinary text, as the backslashes quote characters that could affect the markup. Then the user clicks some control to convert it to code, and that conversion keeps the backslashes, which then appear as literals in code. This first appeared in Stack Overflow a year or so ago (vague memory), and they have not fixed it.

The one and only lib_ppm.o that is visible to your makefile.

I removed an the same error appears

Where are the read_ppm, write_ppm, new_ppm, free_ppm functions defined?

@RenaudPacalet in the lib_ppm.c file

Do you have #include "lib_ppm.h" in zoom.c? If yes, please show the output of make zoom.o.

At this point, it seems the error must be somewhere in "lib_ppm.c".
